# english for terminal, spanish for everything else

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal, language-support

When I open the terminal it's difficult to write "|" or "~" (keyboard layout is in spanish by default).

I know how to change the keyboard layout to a different language, and to have a different language for different applications.

So every time I open the terminal almost always I have to change the keyboard layout. (Well it is not very difficult> move mouse to top panel and then click the keyboard icon, and finally click on English)

It would be better if every time I open the terminal, by default, I could write in English.
There is a way to do that?

Comment: Is your keyboard a spanish one?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && export LANGUAGE=en_US:en && gnome-terminal --window
```

If this works, create a launcher for this command ..